# php check if array key is set and not equal to

Tags: php, arrays

How can I do simple check in the following scenario. This is my array:

[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => blog
        ...
    )

This does not seem to be working:

```
if(isset($data[1]) != "page") { 
   do stuff here...
}
```

I need to check if key [1] is set and value not equal to "page"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution:

```
if(!array_search("page", $data)) {
   // do stuff here
}
```

This works for me

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($data) && isset($data[1]) && $data[1] != 'page') {
   // do something
}
```

You may be thinking, "why isn't he checking if `$data` is an array?" Because it doesn't matter you can access strings from subscripts in PHP.

Comment: Is it necessary to check if the array is set first? It's safe to just check the existence of the index.

Comment: I am checking if the variable exists in scope with `isset($data)`. there is no need to check if it is an array, but you can if you prefer. It won't throw an error.

Comment: I'm saying there's no need to check if the variable exists.

Comment: No. If you try check if a subscript exists in a variable that does not exist, you will get a warning. You always have to check if a variable exists before trying to get values from it.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that isset would discover that the array was undefined and return false at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Isset only returns booleans so you cannot compare the result to the string 'page' you will need to make 2 separate checks.

Also i am not sure if you wanted to check if the first element had page or  that the element at index 1 had page (php arrays start at 0 if you don't define).

But it should be at least something like if(isset(data[1]) && data[1] != 'page')

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong because `isset` will return bool not the value of `$data[1]`.

Anyways, you can try the approach below:

```
    if(isset($data) && array_key_exists(1, $data) && $data[1] != "page")
         do stuff here...
    }
```

`array_key_exist` will return true if `key 1` exists in `$data` array and then will compare the `data[1]` with string.

Comment: You will see `Notice: Undefined variable: data` if data is not set.